# Prove that $|\omega+\omega|=|\omega\cdot\omega|=|\omega^\omega|=|\omega|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> $|\omega+\omega|=|\omega\cdot\omega|=|\omega^\omega|=|\omega|$

Does my attempt look fine or contain logical flaws/gaps? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

We have:

$\omega+\omega=\{\omega+\alpha\mid \alpha<\omega\}$

$\omega\cdot\omega=\{\omega\cdot\alpha \mid \alpha<\omega\}$

$\omega^\omega=\{\omega^\alpha \mid \alpha<\omega\}$

Thus we build bijections $f,g,h$ as follows:

$f:\omega \to \omega+\omega$ such that $f(\alpha)=\omega+\alpha$

$g:\omega \to \omega\cdot\omega$ such that $f(\alpha)=\omega\cdot\alpha$

$h:\omega \to \omega^\omega$ such that $f(\alpha)=\omega^\alpha$

This completes the proof.

Comment: These maps are not going to be surjective for the *correct* definitions..

Comment: You need Zorn's lemma for uncountable sets.

Comment: @Berci Please be more specific! I am unable to understand "the correct definitions".

Comment: Is there some reason you are trying to explicitly construct bijections? You could simply use what you know about cardinals. Two of the equalities are simply sayling that $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. And the third one follows from the fact that union of countably many countable sets is gains countable.

Comment: As previous comment mentioned, what you wrote for $\omega\cdot\omega$ and $\omega^\omega$ differs from the usual definition of ordinal multiplication and ordinal power. Did you perhaps want to write unions of those sets, i.e., something like $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha<\omega} \omega\cdot\alpha$ and $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha<\omega} \omega^\alpha$?

Comment: Thank you so much @MartinSleziak! I got your point. Please confirm my understanding! We have $\omega+\omega=\{\omega+\alpha\mid \alpha<\omega\}$, $\omega\cdot\omega\neq\{\omega\cdot\alpha \mid \alpha<\omega\}$, and $\omega^\omega\neq\{\omega^\alpha \mid \alpha<\omega\}$.

Comment: What you wrote in your recent comment is true. It is also true that $\omega\cdot\omega$ is supremum (union) of all $\omega\cdot\alpha$ where $\alpha<\omega$. Similarly, $\omega^\omega=\sup\{\omega^\alpha; \alpha<\omega\}=\bigcup\{\omega^\alpha; \alpha<\omega\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my confusion @MartinSleziak :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\omega$ × $\omega$ equinumerous to N×N, it is countable.
By induction for all n in N, $\omega^n$ is countable.

$\omega^{\omega}$ = sup$_n$ $\omega^n$ = $\cup_n \omega^n$ is a countable union of countable sets equinumerous to N×N, hence countable.

Finally as $\omega$ + $\omega$ < $\omega$ × $\omega,$ it too is countable.

Comment: How is this helpful to verify the presented proof?